# Wordpress “Categories to tag converter” not working on imported Blogger posts

Tags: plugins, tags, categories

I just imported a blog from blogger to wordpress recently. The blog consisted of about 3500 tags in total. On importing them into wordpress, they were converted to categories for some reason.

I have installed and the **categories to converter** plugin by wordpress that allows you to convert them to tags. On the converter page, i have checked all the categories (using the **check all** button) then clicked on the **convert to tag** button.

However, after waiting for the conversion to take place, the page refreshes and goes back to exactly how it was before i clicked on the button, i.e, nothing is converted. Tried it several times and even uninstalled and re-installed the plugin, but no luck.

Was wondering if someone else has had the same problem and resolved in. I'd appreciate any help

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always perform the transformation at the database level (field taxonomy in wp_term_taxonomy classifies a taxonomy term in a category or tag )